# Proof of a distance

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have one distance shown as an example in a book but I'm striving to demonstrate that it is effectively a distance.

here it is said : let $U=\{z\in\mathbb{C, |z|=1}\}$ we can get a distance on $U$ by setting :

$\forall \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R},\  d(e^{i\alpha}, e^{i\beta})=\inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|\beta - \alpha + 2k\pi|$

And I can't show the triangular inequality : $d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$

here's what I tried : at first I didn't really understood because for me $\inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a set and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are just elements of a set so I didn't understand and then I tried to re-write it a different way :

$d(x,y)=\inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|\arg(y)-\arg(x)+2k\pi|$

then I just tried something here :

$d(x,z)=\inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|\arg(z)-\arg(x)+2k\pi|=\inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|\arg(z)- \arg(y)+\arg(y)-\arg(x)+2k\pi+2k\pi-2k\pi|$

first I wanted to apply the triangular inequality :
$d(x,z)\le \inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\{|\arg(y)-\arg(x)+2k\pi|+|\arg(z)-\arg(y)+2k\pi|+|-2k\pi|\}$

And then, I'm not sure if it's possible to use it here, but I'd say that : because $U$ is a bounded set, then I will use $\inf(A+B)=\inf(A)+\inf(B)$
so it would be :

$d(x,z)\le \inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|\arg(y)-\arg(x)+2k\pi|+\inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|\arg(z)-\arg(y)+2k\pi|+\inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|-2k\pi|$

which would mean : $d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)+\inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|2k\pi|\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$

Is it enough to prove it ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a consequence of the triangle inequality for $\mathbb{R}$.

First note that we have $d(e^{i\alpha}, e^{i\gamma}) = \min_k |\alpha-\gamma + 2 \pi k|$, that is, the $\min$ is attained.

Given $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, choose $k_1,k_2$ such that
$d(e^{i\alpha}, e^{i\beta}) = |\alpha-\beta + 2 \pi k_1| $, 
$d(e^{i\beta}, e^{i\gamma}) = |\beta-\gamma + 2 \pi k_2|$.

We have
$|\alpha-\gamma + 2\pi (k_1+k_2)|  \le |\alpha-\beta + 2 \pi k_1| + |\beta -\gamma+ 2 \pi k_2|$.

Now take the $\min$ of the left hand side to get
\begin{eqnarray}
d(e^{i\alpha}, e^{i\gamma}) &=& \min_k |\alpha-\gamma + 2 \pi k| \\
&\le&  |\alpha-\gamma + 2\pi (k_1+k_2)|  \\
&\le& |\alpha-\beta + 2 \pi k_1| + |\beta -\gamma+ 2 \pi k_2| \\
&=& d(e^{i\alpha}, e^{i\beta}) + d(e^{i\beta}, e^{i\gamma})
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: alright that is very clear thank you !